# Integrate AWS SDK with PHP 2 with Yii Framework

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii, aws-sdk

I'm trying to integrate `AWS SDK for PHP 2` with `Yii Framework`.
I downloaded the ZIP AWS SDK and unzipped on: `/protected/vendors/aws`

```
public function actionTestS3() {
    Yii::import('application.vendors.aws.aws-autoloader');

    $client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key'    => 'XXXX',
        'secret' => 'YYYY',
    ));
}
```

Error:

```
include(S3Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

---

Its not load properly, can someone help me to find how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/IvoRe/ES32) out for an extension that does exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Extensions isn't an option in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('Aws',Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.aws.Aws'));
Yii::setPathOfAlias('Guzzle',Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.aws.Guzzle'));
Yii::setPathOfAlias('Symfony',Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.aws.Symfony'));

Yii::import('application.vendors.aws.aws-autoloader.*');

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
```

Hope this saves someone else time

Answer (score 0):

In your config main.php import the files u need to use .IN which folder u have S3Client.php u have to import those files

For Example

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.vendors.aws.aws-autoloader.*',
),
```

Hope this may help u